# How to patch javascript plugins and keep them maintainable

Tags: javascript, plugins, patch

These days when I code JavaScript I find myself using more and more plugins to accomplish common tasks. Often times when I use an existing plugin, e.g. to display tooltips, I'm not quite happy with certain options - so I extend them, or fix a bug.

This raises the question on how to fix/extend third-party code. Do you just modify the source file? That makes it almost impossible to update the plugin at a later date. You could extend it, by cloning the object or prototyping the existing one. But this often leads to duplicate code or scoping issues.

I've played with the idea of modifying the plugin code directly and generating a patch file at the end. These could then be applied "on build" with phing or some similar framework.

How do you folks handle this problem? Are there any existing projects/frameworks to make this easier?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

If the third party code is a good citizen of open source, you fork it, enhance it, write tests for your enhancement, and submit a pull request back to the project's maintainer. Then your enhancement is available for all to use, including you.  This is how open source happens.

If it's open source, but not a *good citizen* of open source, (no active maintainer, or perhaps your enhancement is too specific or unwelcome for some reason)  the process is the same, they just never accept your pull request.  Later in the future you can merge in changes committed in the official repository on top of your own in your private repository, even if they never make it into the official repository of the project.

This is the reason distributed version control systems like git are so awesome. No one owns the only canonical repository, and your private hacked version can be hosted and treated like the official version very easily.

Of course, most of that assumes that the project is on GitHub somewhere.  If it's not, well, things get much more tricky.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, which is good advice if it's on GitHub. I'm afraid it's not though :) and there will always be situations where you get your hands on a library/plugin/piece of code that isn't hosted on a public version control repository. It's these situations I'm most interested in.

Comment: Without the assistance of version control on your side and the original creators, it gets very hard to handle for the reasons you note. Put more effort into finding higher quality code to use that is hosted in places more friendly to your customized needs (like GitHub). Trust me, that's the only way to stay sane and happy.